# ffmpeg addsubtitle

Tags: php

```
/usr/bin/mencoder -sub /var/www/html/webservice/addsubtitle/subtitle.srt -utf8 -subfont-text-scale 4 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr=128 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4 -ffourcc xvid -o /var/www/html/webservice/upload/videoxplode_rt17ah2ce.mov /var/www/html/webservice/upload/e111105_022234.mov
```

I have added for subtitle some videos using above code. If i can put directly comments line working fine, But i have used above same code using php, that time i got "127" came to me. I am using 64 bit server. Find below code using php..

```
exec ("/usr/bin/mencoder -sub $titlefile -utf8 -subfont-text-scale 4 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr=128 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4 -ffourcc xvid -o $newvideo $filepath",$out, $succ);" "
```

Please anybody can help me on this regards.

Sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 0):

127 is what is being returned from mencoder (which indicates an error).  Can you display `$out` and paste that here?

Also, it's sometimes helpful to see what the exact command is that you're sending to a program.  You might consider changing your line to:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/mencoder -sub $titlefile -utf8 -subfont-text-scale 4 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr=128 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4 -ffourcc xvid -o $newvideo $filepath";
echo $cmd
exec ($cmd,$out, $succ);
```

So you can see whether all your variables are being passed on correctly.

``

Comment: this is my code same error i got$test="/usr/local/bin/mencoder -sub /var/www/html/addsubtitle/subtitle.srt -utf8 -subfont-text-scale 4 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr=128 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4 -ffourcc xvid -o /var/www/html/webservice/upload/rml8ikjg00.mov /var/www/html/webservice/upload/022234.mov");

exec ($test,$out,$succ);
echo "sakthi:".$succ;